# Displaying favico image from database to html using javascript shows "undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, database, undefined, favicon

I have read a lot of similar examples here on S.O yet, I cannot figure out what is the problem. The `item.picture` image is successfully displayed on the html and its url can also be printed on the console.

However, the `favico` displays `undefined` both on the console and on html.
Here is the sample code:

```js
$(function () {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"api/wedding/?format=json&limit=20",
    dataType:"json",
    success :function (data) {
      var listA=$("#wedding_id");
      for(var i=0;i<data.results.length;i++) {
        var  item=newDiv(data.results[i])
        listA.append(item);
      }
    },
    error:function (e) {
      console.log(e) // Better for debugging
      // alert("Error" + e)
    }
  });
});

function newDiv(item)
  {
  if (item.pic) {
    var wed_pic = item.pic.split(",")[0];
  }
  if (item.favico) {
    var favicon = item.favico.split("/")[0]; 
  }
  console.log(item.pic); // <--- can display the pic_url on console
  console.log(favicon); //shows  'undefined'
 
  var template = '<ul class="wedding-list" id='+ item.wedding_id +'>'
               + '<a class="wedding-icon" href="#">' + favicon + '</a>'  //<--- where I think lies the problem
               + '<a class="wed_img" target="_blank" href=' + item.url + '>' 
               + '<img src=' + wed_pic + '>' 
               + '</a> </ul>' +
  return template
  }
```

What could possibly be the cause of the `undefined` error? Thank you for helping.

Comment: and favico is not on the scope...

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, it's ```favicon```, not favico. And it's in the scope

Comment: you **must** learn how to indent properly, if you want to please me use the Whitesmiths style, I hate K&R because it is unreadable and easily confuses  coders

Comment: @MisterJojo: Whitesmith's for JS? :) `return { name: 'John Doe'};`

Comment: @naveen not `Whitesmith's` but [Whitesmiths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style) ;/

Comment: @MisterJojo: https://2ality.com/2013/01/brace-styles.html

Answer (score 0):

for a start

```js
const listA = document.querySelector('#wedding_id')
  ;
fetch ('api/wedding/?format=json&limit')
  .then (res => res.json())
  .then (data =>
    {
    for (let row of data.results)
      listA.appendChild( newDiv(row))  
    })
  .catch (err => console.error(err)) 
  ; 
function newDiv(item)
  {
  let
    e_UL    = document.createElement('ul')
  , wed_pic = !!item?.pic    ? item.pic.split(',')[0]    : ''
  , favicon = !!item?.favico ? item.favico.split('/')[0] : ''
    ;
  console.log('item ----->', JSON.stringify(item,0,2) )
  console.log('wed_pic  ->', wed_pic  )
  console.log('favicon  ->', favicon  ) 
  
  e_UL.id        = item.wedding_id
  e_UL.className = 'wedding-list'
  e_UL.innerHTML = ` 
    <a class="wedding-icon" href="#"> ${favicon} </a> 
    <a class="wed_img" target="_blank" href="${item.url}">
      <img src="${wed_pic}">
    </a>`
    
  return e_UL
  }
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help, although, it still shows 'undefined' (or empty strings) on the console using your code

Comment: @Laenka-Oss  what say the console on this line ? (`console.log('item ----->', JSON.stringify(item,0,2) )`)

Comment: it yields the `key:values` of those columns. Strangely nothing for  `...(item,1) ) )` . All columns exist in the database and can be queried from the `command line` & also visible with  GUI

Comment: @Laenka-Oss how can I have access to the detail of what you indicate? you must certainly misinterpret your data.